# How to use labels inside loops with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

So I'm inside an `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in xs">
    <form>
       <label for="UNIQUELABEL">name</label>
       <input  id="UNIQUELABEL">
       <label for="ANOTHERUNIQUELABEL">name2</label>
       <input  id="ANOTHERUNIQUELABEL">
    </form>
</li>
```

Which should produce something like

```
<li>
    <form>
       <label for="UNIQUELABEL1">name</label>
       <input  id="UNIQUELABEL1">
       <label for="ANOTHERUNIQUELABEL1">name2</label>
       <input  id="ANOTHERUNIQUELABEL1">
    </form>
</li>
<li>
    <form>
       <label for="UNIQUELABEL2">name</label>
       <input  id="UNIQUELABEL2">
       <label for="ANOTHERUNIQUELABEL2">name2</label>
       <input  id="ANOTHERUNIQUELABEL2">
    </form>
</li>
...
```

I'm new to AngularJS and not sure of the right way to approach this (none of the docs use `label` at all).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since `ng-repeat` provides a new scope object on each iteration, I prefer using something like

```
<li ng-repeat="x in xs">
    <form>
       <label for="UNIQUELABEL{{::$id}}_1">name</label>
       <input  id="UNIQUELABEL{{::$id}}_1">
       <label for="UNIQUELABEL{{::$id}}_2">name2</label>
       <input  id="UNIQUELABEL{{::$id}}_2">
    </form>
</li>
```

The advantage of this method is that you are guranteed not to have a duplicate selector with same id on the document. Duplicates could otherwise easily arise when routing or animating.

Comment: This is way better. It is applicable to other use-cases where there's no ng-repeat but you need to assure globally unique id. Just remember to keep UNIQUELABEL.._1 portion unique within angular scope you are in.

Comment: Agree this is better than the accepted answer. The accepted answer is flawed in that if that snippet was used inside an element directive and said directive was used more than once on a page you would end up with elements with the same id!

Comment: I believe $index should be used instead of $id.  $id is unique for each control, not each item in the iteration.

Comment: @GeekyMonkey you are exactly wrong. Firstly ng-repeat creates own scope with a unique $id value, so you premise is wrong. But if we do in fact replace $id with $index, it will possibly create invalid state when coupled with ng-animation, ng-if, ng-show, and other methods of visibility control, as angular routinely creates document fragments as clones, and you could end up with a document that has two tags with the same id.

Comment: Using one-time binding would reduce the number of $watchers, so use {{::$id}}

Answer (score 40):

The correct solution is Gleno's.

`$id` is guaranteed to be unique for every created scope, while `$index` changes with any change to the count of the underlining collection.

You need to add the $index property(zero based) that is available on the scope in the repeater

```
<li ng-repeat="x in xs">
    <form>
       <label for="UNIQUELABEL{{$index+1}}">name</label>
       <input  id="UNIQUELABEL{{$index+1}}">
       <label for="ANOTHERUNIQUELABEL{{$index+1}}">name2</label>
       <input  id="ANOTHERUNIQUELABEL{{$index+1}}">
    </form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 12):

For many scenarios, a better solution might be to enclose both the `<input>` and label text in a single `<label>` element. This is perfectly valid HTML, works properly in all browsers, and has the added benefit of being easy to use with hierarchical data, since you don't need to use the iterator variable:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in xs">
   <label>
       Label Text
       <input type="text">
   </label>
</li>
```