# Angular directive ng-repeat to generate pair of elements input+span

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my request, using directive I try to generate this structure above :

```
<div class='myClass'>
    <input id="id0" name="name0" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="id0" ng-click="myAction('0')"> 0</label>

    <input id="id1" name="name1" type="radio">
    <label for="id1" ng-click="myAction('1')"> 1</label>

    <input id="id2" name="name2" type="radio">
    <label for="id2" ng-click="myAction('2')"> 2</label>

    ...3,4,5...

    span(class="endSpanClass")
```

**Not very trivial:**

I have tried using directive in many ways, ng-repeat but no success to get this pair of input/label together, I mean input+label in same order as in this example.

Then on first element, I expect to get "checked" attribute.

The last span has to be set at the end also.

That kind of try

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$timeout', function(timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: 'MyController',
      scope: {myList: '='},
      template: '<input id="id0" name="view" type="radio">' +
      '<label for="id0" ng-click="myAction(\'day\'> 0 </label>',
      transclude: false,                    
      replace: true,
      link: function($scope, element, attr, ctrl) {


      }
    };
}])
```

And my directive call

```
div(class='myClass')
    input(my-directive, my-list='list', ng-repeat="item in list", id="0", name="name0", type="radio")
```

Gives nothing,

If you can help and gives me some advices, thanks.

J.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use labels inside loops with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663397/how-to-use-labels-inside-loops-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is what I would do:

```
<label ng-repeat="name in names">
  <input name="{{name}}" type="radio"
   ng-checked="$index==0"
   ng-click="myAction($index)"/>
  {{$index}}
</label>
```

1. wrapping form control by `label` which would simplify the code
   also make very explicit what label control what control.
   (just a standard html technique.)
2. use `ng-checked` to control checked state.
3. I would avoid using directive for this short code unless
   it is used many times in many places.
4. if you use directive, template has to have single root element.
   (so you can actually resort to technique [1] above.)

Comment: Looks nice solution, I will test it, but not sure <label> with <input> inside will work as a specific process is applied on this structure then.

Comment: After few tries, here is the solution I get but it is a "shame" as I need to iterate 2 times. My label and my input have to be on same level in Dom, otherwise, lib used can not work. So I make a first ng-repeat with "label", followed by another ng-repeat for "input", with attributes "for" and "id" then label and input looks fine. But shame it is we can not bind ng-repeat to get elements on same level by pair.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple directive definition:

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$timeout', function(timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',      
      scope: {id: '='},
      template: '<div><input id="id{{id}}" name="view" type="radio">' +
      '<label for="id{{id}}" ng-click="myAction(\'{{id}}\')">{{id}}</label></div>',      
      replace: true
    };
}])
```

Along with a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/spQRs5xs43P1FOX7YQzH?p=preview

Comment: BASarat, problem we do not want <div> container as it breaks the rendering process then.